# import.meta.glob imports unused images

Tags: javascript, import, vite

I have a problem with vite and import.meta.glob. I have a dynamic folder with some images and i want to import them. I use

```
const imagesNames = import.meta.glob('../scheme/public/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg}', { as: 'url' })
```

and then filter data with path like

```
for (const key in imagesNames) {
  if (key.includes(import.meta.env.VITE_VARIABLES)) {
    imagesNames[key]().then(mod => {
      images.value[key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)] = mod
    })
  }
}
```

So after build i see that weight of my file index.html much more than i expected.
I can not use switch case because i dont know the folder's name.
I thought i can use variables in import glob but I can not
Please tell me what I need to do

Comment: *I thought i can use variables in import glob but I can not* - are you sure?

Comment: yes i sure. vite docs say that you can not use variable string in meta.glob. only raw string

Comment: Why do you need to filter the images with env variables?

Comment: I work with monorepo, and when someone starts dev, he also writes --filter={code}. therefore, before starting, it declares the variable env. my function imports images from the {code} folder, and I want to make this path dynamic, dependent on the env variable

Comment: And one thing more. I don't know names of images in the folder, so i need to import all of them